# Duplicate entries in PHP error_log using set_exception_handler

Tags: php

I cannot seem to locate the source of this issue.  I actually have nearly the same Docker container and Exception handler lib running in another app.  However, for some reason, I'm getting duplicate log entries in the error log file.

The issue is that it's not just duplicate entries that are the same (that'd be another interesting issue).  It's the same Exception being logged and the same stack trace, but one is from my custom Exception handler (JSON), and the other is the default PHP error log handler (or so it seems - tested with CLI SAPI as well as PHP-FPM).

I was under the assumption that PHP wouldn't write to the log file if an exception handler was set.  I'm also executing `die(1)` at the end of the callback function for the Exception handler.

Again, all of the Exception handling code seems to be working well.  It's just that PHP is still logging the Exception.  Is there a setting or something else that I'm missing here needing to be done on the PHP config side?

Below is a copy of the error log output:

```
[24-Nov-2018 02:20:11 UTC] PHP Exception:  Testing in /srv/www/boot/common.php on line 65
[24-Nov-2018 02:20:11 UTC] PHP Stack trace:
[24-Nov-2018 02:20:11 UTC] PHP   1. {main}() /srv/www/public/index.php:0
[24-Nov-2018 02:20:11 UTC] PHP   2. require() /srv/www/public/index.php:13
{"timestamp":"2018-11-24 02:20:11 UTC","level":"critical","message":"Testing","app_version":{},"environment":"dev","class":"Exception","file":"\/srv\/www\/boot\/common.php","line":65,"code":0,"previous":null,"trace":[{"file":"\/srv\/www\/public\/index.php","line":13,"function":"require"}],"user":[],"tags":[],"extra":[],"output_buffers":[]}
```

Comment: Do you want to turn off the php error log ? If yes then you can use ini_set("log_errors", 0); and it will not log errors any more.

Comment: @Akhilesh Is that a requirement?  I thought that wasn't necessary if you've set a custom Exception handler.  I have the same `log_errors = On` on another PHP Docker container without this issue, so I guess I'm confused.

Comment: I think its changed in php 7 http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-exception-handler.php.  Caution
Note that providing an explicit Exception type hint for the ex parameter in your callback will cause issues with the changed exception hierarchy in PHP 7.   I think this will help you.

Comment: No, that's not the issue.  I'm using a `\Throwable` typehint for the callback function.  Also, I'm throwing an Exception here for testing, not an "Error"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going to leave this here for anyone that might come across this.  The issue turned out to be XDebug which hijacks your Exceptions.  It was enabled on this particular app in our dev env.